# Comparing strings that use the substring method

Tags: android, substring

I hope somebody could give me an explaination why the below code wont work:

```
            //Why doesnt this work
            String l = myString.substring(cut,  lengthLastBtn-1);
            String c = myString.substring(cut,  lengthLastBtn-1);

            if(l==c){
                Log.i(TAG, "Correct");
            }
            //End

            //This work!
            String l = "hi";
            String c = "hi";

            if(l==c){
                Log.i(TAG, "Correct");
            }
            // End

            // Or if i want the Vars as in the first code i have to use the if statement like this
            if(l.contains(c)){
                Log.i(TAG, "Correct");
            }
            //End
```

So, why cant a compare a string when i have used the substring method on it. I even see in the log for the strings that they are the same, or have the same text at least.

Comment: `==` compares the strings by object identity, not by contents.

Comment: You should just use the `equals()` method instead.

Comment: What are `strings that use the substring method`?!

Comment: Thanks for the fast replys, the equals did the trick. The link was very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the “==“ operator with String`s, it means a comparison between objects, not the value that objects hold.

In order to compare `String`s values , you should use the built-in method [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). The result is true if the `String` object represents the same sequence of characters.

```
if(string1.equals(string2)) {
     //Match 
}
```